# Find integrable combination to solve system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

There is the system:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\dot{x} = -xy^2+x+y \\ 
\dot{y} = -x-y+x^2y 
\end{array}
\right.
$$

the way it should be solved is to find an **integrable combination** [there is the description](http://faculty.uml.edu/Dimitris_Christodoulou/Teaching/documents/handbook_DE.pdf) (page 349 of pdf document).

I've already tried multiplying the first equation by $x$, the second one by $y$ then adding first to second so I got: $xdx+ydy = x^2 - y^2$, which I have no idea how to integrate.

Also I tried multiplying the first by $y$, the second by $x$, also adding first to second so I got: $ydx+xdy=(xy - 1)(x^2 - y^2)$, which I also don't know how to integrate.

Could you plese provide any **integrating combinations** or ideas how to deal with equations I got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good start, except that you should write $\dot x$ and $\dot y$ instead of $dx$ and $dy$.

Anyway, you have
$$
(\tfrac12 (x^2+y^2))\dot{} = x \dot x + y \dot y = x^2-y^2
$$
and
$$
(xy)\dot{} = \dot x y + x \dot y = (xy-1)(x^2-y^2)
.
$$
These can be combined to give
$$
(xy)\dot{} = (xy-1) (\tfrac12 (x^2+y^2))\dot{}
$$
so that either $xy-1=0$ identically or
$$
\frac{(xy)\dot{}}{xy-1} = (\tfrac12 (x^2+y^2))\dot{}
$$
where both sides can be integrated to find a constant of motion.

Can you take it from there, or do you need further hints?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I used your steps and got $ce^{x^2+y^2}=(xy-1)^2$. As I know after that we should express $x$ or $y$ from there and substitute the result to one of the equations so we get $x(t)$ or $y(t)$. Am I right or there is some another way get the answer (cause mine seems to be too complicated :))

Comment: There also was Cauchy problem in the task so I've tried to use to simplify my task. It is: $x(2)=1$, $y(2)=1$. I substituted it to the result above and got that $c=0$ hence $1=xy$ hence $x=\frac{1}{y}$. Then I substituted this to the second equation and got $\frac{dy}{y} = -dt$. Am I right doing this?

Comment: @ЕгорПономарёв: Looks fine! I doubt it's possible to find expressions for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ in the general case (in practice, that is; it's always possible *in principle* once you have a constant of motion).

Comment: Also, $\dot{x} + \dot{y} \equiv 0$, hence $\frac{d}{dt}(x(t) + y(t)) \equiv 0$ and $x(t) + y(t) \equiv x(0) + y(0)$.

Comment: @Evgeny: No, that would have been too easy! Note that it's $\dot x + \dot y = -xy^2 + x^2 y = xy (x-y) \neq 0$.

Comment: @HansLundmark My bad, I really messed up $xy^2$ with $x^2y$. I shouldn't write around midnight :)